# Equal Core Data statement to SQLite statement (order by ... desc..)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I'm using a statement in sqlite to select specific object from table:

```
 NSString *statment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM %@ ORDER BY %@ DESC LIMIT 1", TRAP_TABLE, DISTANCE_TO_CLOSE_POINT];
```

I want to do the same thing using core data.
How should I mix the `NSPredicate` & `NSSortDescriptor` in order to do the same?

EDIT:
This is what I did, didn't tried it yet:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:DISTANCE_TO_CLOSE_POINT ascending:NO selector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NSPredicate` is like the where clause of a SQL statement.  Your example doesn't have a where clause.

In a `NSFetchRequest` you can add sort descriptors to handle the 'order by'.  Also in the `NSFetchRequest` you can set a fetch limit.

From there you pass the `NSFetchRequest` to the `NSManagedObjectContext` and receive your results.

### Update 1

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:DISTANCE_TO_CLOSE_POINT ascending:NO selector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];
```

That is overkill in this situation.  I am guessing the value you are sorting on is a number which means you don't need `localizedCompare:` since you are not working with strings.  So you can simplify it to:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:DISTANCE_TO_CLOSE_POINT ascending:NO];
```

And if you are in an ARC project, even reduce it down to:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:DISTANCE_TO_CLOSE_POINT ascending:NO];
```

Which can then be thrown directly into the `NSFetchRequest`:

```
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:DISTANCE_TO_CLOSE_POINT ascending:NO]]];
```

Comment: Eventually I did: NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:DISTANCE_TO_CLOSE_POINT ascending:NO selector:@selector(localizedCompare:)]; , I don't know if it's ok.